# jQuery: Remove background once Ajax request has loaded?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created my own tooltips using jQuery + Ajax to load the content from an external file...great! - trouble is... I have a loading.gif animation running on the background of the container, which once the ajax content loads, I want to remove... Any idea how I can do this with my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.ttip').hover(function(){
    var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
    //console.log(offset)
    var width = jQuery(this).outerWidth();
var tooltipId = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
    jQuery('#tooltip-cont').empty().load('tooltips.html ' + tooltipId).fadeIn(500);
    jQuery('#tooltip-cont').css({top:offset.top, left:offset.left + width + 10}).show();
}, function(){
    jQuery('#tooltip-cont').stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
});
    });
</script>
```

Note: I've solved this by setting the elements inside the #tooltip-cont - to a higher z-index that that of itself.

Comment: Which element contains your loading spinner?

Comment: #tooltip-cont is the container div

Answer (score 0):

In the "success" section of your AJAX call, add:

```
jQuery('#tooltip-cont').hide().
```

If you could add your AJAX call to the question I can be more specific.

Comment: Wouldn't that just hide the main container for the tooltip and all it's contents?

Comment: I don't have your HTML, how would I know?

Comment: Well the the only jQuery I use is above in my post...and the tooltip container I use is div id="tooltip-cont"></div>

Comment: Show your HTML in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the background image in a css class and add that class to the container, when the ajax comes back with the content, you can just remove the class from the container with the .removeClass()

CodeyMonkey:: Just checking back to the site, sorry for the delay. An example as requested. Assuming that the control where the loading image should be displayed is $('#tooltip-cont').

put this in your css
    .loadingImage{
    background-image:"\anyimage.png";
    }

Use this to add the class with the background loading image to the control(div or other)
     $('#tooltip-cont').addClass("loadingImage");

Use this when you want to remove the class after the information has loaded

```
 $('#tooltip-cont').removeClass("loadingImage");
```

putting it all together

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.ttip').hover(function(){
  $('#tooltip-cont').addClass("loadingImage");
        var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
        //console.log(offset)
        var width = jQuery(this).outerWidth();
    var tooltipId = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
        jQuery('#tooltip-cont').empty().load('tooltips.html ' + tooltipId, function(){
$('#tooltip-cont').removeClass("loadingImage");
}).fadeIn(500);
        jQuery('#tooltip-cont').css({top:offset.top, left:offset.left + width +  
   10}).show();
    }, function(){
        jQuery('#tooltip-cont').stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
    });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you give me a quick jquery example using my code above please?

Comment: if that's not too much trouble?